# AWS: Website with multiple DB instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, rds

I have hosted website on AWS. Currently we have only 1 RDS.

Can we make copy of that 1 DB instance and make another? And by setting load balancer as per the request comes (when high traffic).

Ideas is to get on high traffic, manage AWS via load balancer & multiple DB instances (RDS).

How to setup those things? as I am new to AWS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With more information about what you're trying to achieve and why we might be able to help more.

**Read Replicas**

You can create multiple [RDS Read Replicas](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/read-replicas/), then offload some of the database traffic to those replicas. Writes go to the master database. This is separate from RDS Multi-AZ which is for reliability rather than scale.

**Finding the Bottleneck**

While the database can be the bottleneck, it's not always the problem. Before you look at scaling out you should look at why your database is so busy. Is it indexed correctly? Do you have slow queries? Are the SQL queries optimised? You should have a good DBA look at it if you haven't already.

**Alternate Databases**

Do you need a relational database, or can you use a NoSQL database like [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) for some or all of your data? NoSQL databases are typically much easier to scale.

**Caching**

Could you alter your application code to query an [Elasticache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) instance before querying the database? It's more flat than relational, but it's much, much faster as everything is in memory.

**Vertical Scaling**

Sometimes the easiest option it to just use a bigger server. You can't easily auto-scale up and down, but if you can afford it, it can be less work.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what DB engine you're using. If your RDS runs MySQL 5.6 you can either use [**Aurora Multi-Master**](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/amazon-aurora-multimaster-now-generally-available/) where you can add more DB nodes as needed or [**Aurora Serverless**](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) that automatically adds small DB nodes on demand.

With other RDS DB engines (all non-Aurora ones, or Aurora PgSQL) it may not be that trivial.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Using Aurora on AWS